# Encrypting member data with keyfiles

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, pdo, mcrypt

I am working on a website where I want members to be able to maintain a list of items in their account. In addition, they should be able to see/browse all items owned by others member (except without seeing any ownership information).

I want to be able to offer some practical reassurance of security to members so that if they log into their account from a device that doesn’t have their keyfile, they will still be able to access and use their account but it will just be limited because it won’t show up that they own any items (and consequently won’t have the privileges to update any of their items or create new items). I’ve been trying to get it working with something like below but I’m not having much - any advisce would be much appreciate!...

```
<?php

#Encryption/decryption functions ;
function encrypt($value, $key) {
    $ivSize = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC); 
    $iv     = mcrypt_create_iv($ivSize, MCRYPT_RAND); 
    return    mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $value, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv); 
}
function decrypt($value, $key) {
    $ivSize = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC); 
    $iv     = mcrypt_create_iv($ivSize, MCRYPT_RAND); 
    return    mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $value, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
}

#Encryption key that would normally be seeded by user ;
$keyfile='9TOxo1Uy5JsiW1jRPS61';



#Database sandbox;
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------;
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mydb;host=localhost', 'root', '' );
#$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

#Create dummy table ;
$db->exec("CREATE table items (
owner_id VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL,
ownername VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL, 
itemname VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL,
itemdetails VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL);");



#Populate with test data ;
session_start();
$insert= $db->prepare("INSERT INTO items(owner_id, ownername, itemname, itemdetails) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
$_SESSION['user_id']=0001;
$db->execute(array(encrypt($_SESSION['user_id'],$keyfile)),"Bob","Bobs 1st Item","Item description of Bobs first item");
$db->execute(array(encrypt($_SESSION['user_id'],$keyfile)),"Bob","Bobs 2nd Item","Item description of Bobs second item");
$_SESSION['user_id']=0002;
$db->execute(array(encrypt($_SESSION['user_id'],$keyfile)),"Tom","Toms Item","Item description of Toms first item");


#Only return items belonging to the current user - but returns nothing without their keyfile present even if the user is logged in)
$userquery = $db->prepare(" SELECT decrypt(ownername, :ownerkey) as ownername, itemname, itemdetails FROM items WHERE $_SESSION('userid') == decrypt(owner_id, :ownerkey) ");
$userquery->execute(array(':ownerkey'=> "$keyfile"));
$result=$userquery->fetchall();


#Without their keyfile a user can still search the items table but with meaningless owner information ;
$fullquery = $db->prepare("SELECT ownername, itemname, itemdetails FROM items");
$userquery->execute();
$result=$fullquery->fetchall();


?>
```

Comment: The `INSERT` statement names four columns, but provides only three value placeholders.  Also, the string quotation characters used from the first `SELECT` statement onwards are curly, rather than straight.

Comment: Thanks @eggyal - I've updated my code above following your corrections...is this the smart way to go about getting the functionality I'm after?

Comment: You aren't encrypting anything but the `user_id` - a database breech would still release all this data in plain text

Comment: Hey @CᴴᵁᴮᴮʸNᴵᴺᴶᴬ (love the nametag!) - yes good point I see that now - although perhaps I can put another layer of encryption of the whole site afterwards? However I'm just trying to anonymise the `owner_id` field so that members can see that without their keyfile, even they can't see which items belong to them or add new items

Comment: @Bendy in that case how are the users storing their keyfile, i once done something similar but struggled to store the 'keyfile' indefinitely in the users browsers. Or are you going to store the keyfiles in another table and assign it to the user on authentication/login?

Comment: If the latter, then the way you've gone about it works well to detach the data from the user. Although I would personally just replace the owner_id and ownername in the outputted table with *Hidden*

Comment: Thanks - I hadn't considered storing keyfiles in another table! :) I have been planning that they could download the keyfile (seeded from their user_id for example) and then they'd be warned that they are responsible for keeping it on USB stick/phone etc to authenticate in future (although your idea of having it encrypted on another table would be nice for them to be able to download it again if/when they lose it(!)).

Comment: I like the 'Hidden' idea actually - although I want to be able to give a practical demonstration at events (it's a website for non-techie people) so want to be able to demonstrate 'physical' security for them to fee reassured that it's not just being hidden if that makes sense