# DES Encryption and Decryption in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, des

Please help. How do I make an array in encrypt and decrypt?

```
<?php
    class DES{

        function encrypt($plainText, $cipherKey){
            //plainText
            $result = $this->toBiner($plainText);
            $result = $this->InitialPermutation($result);
            //key
            $key = $this->toBiner($cipherKey);
            $key = $this->kompresBit($key);
            $arrLeftShift = $this->LeftShift($key);
            //final
            $result = $this->keyExpansion($result, $arrLeftShift);
            return $result;
        }

        function decrypt($encryptedText, $cipherKey){
            $key = $this->toBiner($cipherKey);
            $key = $this->kompresBit($key);
            $arrLeftShift = $this->LeftShift($key);

            $result = $this->reverseKeyExpansion($encryptedText, $arrLeftShift);
            $result = $this->revInitialPermutation($result);
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code?  Does this work?  Does it not work?  Do you see any errors?  What do you need help with?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much on encryption but from what I understand, DES isn't a recommended encryption standard:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard

If you're after something more secure, have a look at the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28814737/encrypting-member-data-with-keyfiles) that includes a encryption/decryption functions that work